# Calculate difference between two dates in Webform

Tags: 8, theming, webforms

I am trying to calculate a difference in days between (a) the date a Webform was completed and (b) an "Event Date" field on the Webform. I have added a Computed Twig field to the webform and attempted to use this code (similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27205095/1357555):

```
{% set difference = date(data.event_date).diff(date(completed)) %}
{% set leftDays = difference.days %}
```

However, I am getting an error message when attempting to save the field.

> *Computed value/markup* is not valid.
>
> - Calling "diff" method on a "DateTime" object is not allowed in "{# inline_template_start #}{{ completed|date }} {{ data.date_needed|date }} {% set difference = date(data.event_date).diff(date(completed)) %} {% set leftDays = difference.days %}" at line 4.
>
> Failed to render computed Twig value due to error.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question, but here's my workaround: `{% set difference = data.date_needed|date('U') - completed %}` to find the difference based on Unix time. Then `{% set leftDays = (difference / 60 / 60 / 24)|round(0, 'ceil') %}` to get a "number of days" value.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the Webform module. I created the below ticket to address this issue.

[Improve Computed Twig element validation to support complex calculations](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2966638)